# Error running python script to create google ldap configuration on Macos

Tags: python, macos, ldap

I'm trying to run the following script to create a mass configuration deployment. The script should read a `plist` file and create an LDAP configuration on my Macbook.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from OpenDirectory import ODNode, ODSession, kODNodeTypeConfigure
from Foundation import NSMutableData, NSData
import os
import sys

####read plist####

GOOGLELDAPCONFIGFILE = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
CONFIG = GOOGLELDAPCONFIGFILE.read()
GOOGLELDAPCONFIGFILE.close()

####write plist####

od_session = ODSession.defaultSession()
od_conf_node, err = ODNode.nodeWithSession_type_error_(od_session, kODNodeTypeConfigure, None)

request = NSMutableData.dataWithBytes_length_(b'\x00'*32, 32)
request.appendData_(NSData.dataWithBytes_length_(CONFIG, len(CONFIG)))

response, err = od_conf_node.customCall_sendData_error_(99991, request, None)

####Edit the default search path and append the new node to allow for login####

os.system("dscl -q localhost -append /Search CSPSearchPath /LDAPv3/ldap.google.com")
os.system("bash -c 'echo -e \"TLS_IDENTITY\tLDAP Client\" >> /etc/openldap/ldap.conf' ")
```

However I always get this error:

> ```
> % sudo python3 ldap.py ldap.plist
>
> Password:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/user/Downloads/ldap.py", line 17, in <module>
>     request.appendData_(NSData.dataWithBytes_length_(CONFIG, len(CONFIG)))
> TypeError: Expecting byte-buffer, got str
> ```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `pyobjc-framework-opendirectory` with:

```
python3 -m pip install pyobjc-framework-opendirectory
```

I have the same issue since MacOS 12.3+. I am keeping my systems on 12.2 until I myself figure this out. The code looks the way it is suppose to look prior to 12.3 and based on Google's recommendations.

So far all I could dig up is that of the OpenDirectory modules being updated on 12.3+

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I have version 8.5 of pyobjc-framework-OpenDirector, still doesn't work. I'm using MacOS 12.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `request.appendData_(NSData.dataWithBytes_length_(str.encode(CONFIG), len(CONFIG)))`. For me it works. I advise you to read something about python 2 and 3 differences. Good Luck!