# Problem with Python script when setting up LDAP for MacOS

Tags: python-ldap

I am trying to set up Google secure LDAP on my Macbook Pro running Monterey 12.3 following these instructions from Google.

```
request.appendData_(NSData.dataWithBytes_length_(CONFIG,
len(CONFIG))) TypeError: Expecting byte-buffer, got str
```

See the script from the guide:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from OpenDirectory import ODNode, ODSession, kODNodeTypeConfigure
from Foundation import NSMutableData, NSData

import os
import sys

# Reading plist
GOOGLELDAPCONFIGFILE = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
CONFIG = GOOGLELDAPCONFIGFILE.read()
GOOGLELDAPCONFIGFILE.close()

# Write the plist
od_session = ODSession.defaultSession()
od_conf_node, err = ODNode.nodeWithSession_type_error_(od_session, kODNodeTypeConfigure, None)
request = NSMutableData.dataWithBytes_length_(b'\x00'*32, 32)
request.appendData_(NSData.dataWithBytes_length_(CONFIG, len(CONFIG)))
response, err = od_conf_node.customCall_sendData_error_(99991, request, None)

# Edit the default search path and append the new node to allow for login
os.system("dscl -q localhost -append /Search CSPSearchPath /LDAPv3/ldap.google.com")
os.system("bash -c 'echo -e \"TLS_IDENTITY\tLDAP Client\" >> /etc/openldap/ldap.conf' ")
```

I have tried to find some solutions on Google (e.g. .encode, b'..) But I do not really understand it.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution, actually here it was posted earlier.

[Error running python script to create google ldap configuration on Macos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72432082/error-running-python-script-to-create-google-ldap-configuration-on-macos)